# Can someone please Verify my uart packet?

Tags: uart

I have a thermal camera that I've been trying to get working for far too long.  I have the datasheet and the uart framing instructions.  But I can only get a NAK (0xFC) response out of the camera.

The packet framing is 11bytes fixed length with checksum.  The checksum is calculated by summing all the command and data bytes as unsigned integers.

All multi byte quantities representing integers or word values are sent LSB first.
Unused bytes in the data command portion are set to zero.

The packet structure is as follows:
1 byte specifying command length (not including this byte)
2 bytes specifying command function
6 bytes specifying command data
2 bytes checksum

Here is the command for setting a filter position:
command: 0x00A1
word0:1 (position1)
word1:0
word2:0

I came up with the following string and have tried many variations of it in realterm, with no luck:
0x0A 0x1A 0x00 0x10 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0xA2

What do you think?

tried my string
expected ACK (0xFB) response
recieved NAK (0xFC) response (timeout or checksum error)

Comment: Since "*packet framing is 11bytes fixed length*" and "*2 bytes specifying command function*", what is the purpose for "*1 byte specifying command length*"?  Instead of your version, I'd would rather read what the manufacturer actually provides.

Comment: That was from the manufacturer sheet.  That's what the manufacturer wants for the framing. I'm trying to comply, but can't get through.  Was hoping you might see an error in my frame.

Comment: I'll scan the command sheet if you think you can decifer.

Comment: "*That's what the manufacturer wants for the framing*" -- Beware your ambiguous use of "*frame*". A UART frames each byte of data; the UART has no concept of a message or packet or datagram. IMO *format* is a better word choice for the packet/message.

Comment: Heres my google drive link to the protocol and one of the command pages.  For the first one i get 0x0A 0x90 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x09. Id really appreciate it if someone could tell me what they see.  Thanks.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1lFMM2IkxjAVbiFed2XCL-4BxDJLAZHno?usp=drive_link

Comment: Some quick observations & errors on your part: (1) the doc mentions "packet" whereas you (mis)use "*frame*". (2) the data in your packet for (***set***) "*filter position*" doesn't make sense: the command value is wrong and (3) the data seems to be out-of-range. (4) the checksum in your packet is miscalculated and (5) stored out of order. (6) We need the entire doc, not just two pages.

Comment: I assume "*LSB*" was meant as little-endian ordering.  But you seem to have choosen a third option (neither bit nor byte), and are constructing the packet with least-significant *nibble* ordering. And then not bothering to apply any ordering at all to the checksum (contrary to spec). A command code of 0x00A1 would be two bytes in the packet as `0xA1 0x00`. A data word of 0x0001 would be two bytes in the packet as `0x01 0x00`. The simple checksum would be two bytes in the packet as `0xA2 0x00`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I assume "LSB" was meant as little-endian ordering. But you seem to have choosen a third option (neither bit nor byte), and are constructing the packet with least-significant nibble ordering. And then not bothering to apply any ordering at all to the checksum (contrary to spec). A command code of 0x00A1 would be two bytes in the packet as 0xA1 0x00. A data word of 0x0001 would be two bytes in the packet as 0x01 0x00. The simple checksum would be two bytes in the packet as 0xA2 0x00. –
sawdust

Thank you.